# Chain rule flaw patch with George Simmons approach in Calculus With Analytic Geometry page 94

Tags: calculus, chain-rule

\begin{aligned} \frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \end{aligned}

Chain Rule says we can solve it this way:

\begin{aligned} \frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{dy}{du} * \frac{du}{dx} 
 \end{aligned}

The above equation comes with below proving process:

1, somehow we think using the below equation is a good idea,

\begin{aligned} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} \end{aligned}

2, then we convert: $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}$ to $ \frac{dy}{dx}$ form

\begin{align} \frac{dy}{dx} &= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}\\&= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}]\\&= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u}] * \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}]\\&= \lim_{\Delta u\to 0} [\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u}] * \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}]\\&= \frac{dy}{du} * \frac{du}{dx} \end{align}

But since we have replaced: $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}$ to $ \lim_{\Delta u\to 0}$
, it might not be legitimate to do so, the  ${\Delta u}$ might becomes $0$ as${\Delta x \to 0}$

So George Simmons in his book "Calculus With Analytic Geometry" page 94-95 mentioned:

\begin{aligned} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} &= \frac{dy}{du} + \epsilon \\
\Rightarrow  \Delta y &= \frac{dy}{du} * \Delta u + \epsilon * \Delta u  \\
\Rightarrow  \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} &= \frac{dy}{du} *\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + \epsilon * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} \\
\Rightarrow \frac{dy}{dx} &= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\frac{dy}{du} *\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + \epsilon * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}] \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\lim_{\Delta u\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} *\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + \epsilon * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}] \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} + \epsilon * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}] \\
&= \frac{dy}{dx} + \epsilon * \frac{du}{dx} \end{aligned}

But why we are doing it this way? I truly dont understand it, why not writeing this way? $\lim_{\Delta x\to 0}  \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} = \frac{dy}{du} + \epsilon$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

His argument is that when one writes

\begin{equation}\lim _{{\Delta} u \rightarrow  0} \frac{{\Delta} y}{{\Delta} u} = \frac{d y}{d u}\end{equation}

it actually means

\begin{equation}\lim _{\substack{{\Delta} u \rightarrow  0\\
{\Delta} u \neq  0
}} \frac{{\Delta} y}{{\Delta} u} = \frac{d y}{d u}\end{equation}

so one cannot write

\begin{equation}\frac{{\Delta} y}{{\Delta} u} = \frac{d y}{d u}+{\epsilon}\end{equation}

when there is a risk that $ {\Delta} u = 0$. In the case of the
chain rule, he says that $u$ depends on $x$, so when $ {\Delta} x \neq  0$, it is not necessarily true that
$ {\Delta} u \neq  0$. So instead of writing the above, he
writes

\begin{equation}{\Delta} y = \frac{d y}{d u} {\Delta} u+{\epsilon} {\Delta} u\end{equation}

which remains true even when $ {\Delta} u = 0$.

So the proof of the chain rule is now

\begin{equation}\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{2}  \begin{array}{rcl}\displaystyle  \lim _{{\Delta} x \rightarrow  0} \frac{{\Delta} y}{{\Delta} x}&=&\displaystyle  \lim _{{\Delta} x \rightarrow  0} \left(\frac{d y}{d u} \frac{{\Delta} u}{{\Delta} x}+{\epsilon} \left({\Delta} u\right) \frac{{\Delta} u}{{\Delta} x}\right)\\
&=&\displaystyle  \frac{d y}{d u} \lim _{{\Delta} x \rightarrow  0} \frac{{\Delta} u}{{\Delta} x}+\displaystyle  \lim _{{\Delta} x \rightarrow  0} {\epsilon} \left({\Delta} u\right) \displaystyle  \lim _{{\Delta} x \rightarrow  0} \frac{{\Delta} u}{{\Delta} x}\\
&=&\displaystyle  \frac{d y}{d u} \frac{d u}{d x}+{0}\times{\frac{d u}{d x}}\\
&=&\displaystyle  \frac{d y}{d u} \frac{d u}{d x}
\end{array}\end{equation}

In this derivation, we never divide by $\Delta u$.

I think he could have introduced the Taylor expansion of order 1, which
would clarify the argument.

Comment: Lets just focus on this, does removing lim gives us the permission to add error to the equation? 
\begin{equation}\frac{{\Delta} y}{{\Delta} u} = \frac{d y}{d u}+{\epsilon}\end{equation} 
Or this:
\begin{equation}\lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{{\Delta} y}{{\Delta} u} = \frac{d y}{d u}\end{equation}

Comment: If we remove the limit, the difference $\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} - \frac{d y}{d u}$ is not equal to 0. Instead it is a quantity that tends to 0 when $\Delta u \to 0$. In differential calculus, quantities that tend to 0 are often denoted $\epsilon$. This $\epsilon$ depends on $\Delta u$, so it would be more rigourous to write $\epsilon(\Delta u)$.

Comment: So the first step is to remove lim and re-write as 
\begin{equation}\frac{{\Delta} y}{{\Delta} u} = \frac{d y}{d u}+{\epsilon}\end{equation}
and then convert the equation to
\begin{equation}\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{dy}{du} *\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + \epsilon * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} \end{equation}
And put lim back to get our new equation
\begin{equation}\frac{dy}{dx} = \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x} = \frac{dy}{dx} + \epsilon * \frac{du}{dx}\end{equation}
Since we have extra \epsilon \to 0 if \Delta u \to 0, but I still not understand

Comment: I didn't felt the "ingenious bit of mathematical 
trickery" he mentioned in the book, I thought I didn't saw his view, please enlight me

Comment: Remember that the $\epsilon$ depends on $\Delta u$ and that $\Delta u\to 0$ when $\Delta x \to 0$, so in the limit, there is no $\epsilon$ anymore and the new equation is $\frac{d y}{ d x} = \frac{d y}{d u}\frac{d u }{d x}$.

Comment: I see, so it should flows this way:
\begin{aligned} &= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\frac{dy}{du} *\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + \epsilon(\Delta u) * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}] \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\lim_{\Delta u\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} *\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + \epsilon(\Delta u) * \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x}] \\
&= \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} [\lim_{\Delta u\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} *\frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} + 0] \\
&= \lim_{\Delta u\to 0} \frac{\Delta y}{\Delta u} * \lim_{\Delta x\to 0} \frac{\Delta u}{\Delta x} \\
&= \frac{dy}{du}*\frac{du}{dx}
  \end{aligned}